# Detecting just started applications

Tags: java

I need to write a java code that watches the applications. Whenever the user starts an applications (game, IE, Office...) it should write down the name of the application and the date it just started.
Is this doable in Java? Can anyone provide me with some code hints?
Note that am using a windows machine.

Comment: I have been researching this. All i found is that this can be done using JNI which i dont want to use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this is not doable in pure Java. It requires calling OS APIs, which can be done in Java by using [JNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JNI) or (better) [JNA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Access), but Java is not really a good option for doing this kind of things.

Comment: +1 because : "Java is not really a good option for doing this kind of things" , there are better options in this area.

Comment: Just curious here. Are C or C++ the better options alluded here, if one does not want to use C# on Windows?

Comment: @Kishor Nanda: yes, the Windows API is basically a C API

Answer (score 2):

If you are on Windows you can retrieve this information from the (Windows Management Interface) [WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394582%28VS.85%29.aspx). Take a look at [jWMI](http://henryranch.net/software/jwmi-query-windows-wmi-from-java/) .

Answer (score 1):

Additional to JNI you always can execute a shell command (such as tasklist) in a periodically thread  and read the output.